# Replace number with barcode in HTML document automatically

Tags: javascript, html, barcode

Right, this may be an odd one. When I print invoices from a website it gives me a html document to print, save, etc. Within that is a 'sales record number' (6 digits) in the same place each time:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
<tbody><tr bgcolor="#cccccc">
<td nowrap="nowrap">
<font color="#666666"><b>Date</b></font>
</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap">
<font color="#666666"><b>Sales&nbsp;Record #</b></font>
</td>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
<td nowrap="nowrap">18-Apr-2013</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap">111111</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

So '111111' is the sales record #. I need this to show as a barcode, either in place of the number or somewhere on the page separately. I have to print around 300 of these a day, so needs to be automated somehow. I've tried using sed and the usual things but no luck :(

Cheers!

Comment: Which symbology would you like to use? Code 128, Interleaved 2 of 5, 39? Does it matter? Will it always be numeric with an even number of characters?

Comment: It doesn't actually matter too much to be honest, it's for my own use just to automatically label a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should use http://code.google.com/p/jquery-barcode/
I suppose that HTML alone is not enough try to use javascript and the right library.

Comment: Cheers! I shall check that out, may be precisely what I'm after :)